# amp-access - Authorization vs Pingback

Tags: authorization, amp-html

## Question: What's the difference between them?

By reading the [docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-access#authorization-endpoint_1) I can see some differences (listed below), but I have the impression that I don't need [Pingback](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-access#pingback-endpoint), in other words, I can implement everything (count down the number of free views of the page; map the AMP Reader ID to the Publisher’s identity) using just the [Authorization endpoint](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-access#authorization-endpoint).

Am I right or am I missing something here?

---

## Some differences that I've noticed

- [Authorization endpoint](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-access#authorization-endpoint_1)

  - credentialed CORS GET endpoint
  - mandatory
  - produces the authorization response
  - AMP runtime may need to call Authorization endpoint multiple times per document impression. This can happen when AMP Runtime believes that the access parameters for the Reader have changed significantly, e.g. after a successful Login Flow
- [Pingback endpoint](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-access#pingback-endpoint_1)

  - credentialed CORS POST endpoint
  - optional
  - does not produce a response
  - called when the Reader has started viewing the document and after the Reader has successfully completed the Login Flow.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @noogui, right now I'm studying AMP, therefore it is just a question regarding a topic in the documentation that I don't understand (i.e. Is it possible to implement something using Pingback that is not possible using Authorization?). Does this make my question a bad question?

Comment: your question is relevant (and interesting to use) WHEN it is framed according to a MCV. As we also are working on this type of problem, we'll offer advice - but based on your MCV.

Comment: ok, I'll try to build a MCV for you guys =)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation,

> AMP Runtime calls this endpoint automatically when the Reader has
>   **started** viewing the document

I am not sure what determines when the reader has started viewing the document. But the authorization endpoint is triggered **before** the user has started reading the document. pingback endpoint can be used to verify that the user has actually started to view the document and update meter counts accordingly.